# getting exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap while starting tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to start tomcat from command prompt getting below error

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin>java org.apache.catal
ina.startup.Bootstrap

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/catalina/s tartup/Bootstrap
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) Could not find the main class: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap. 
>   Program window

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you edit the tomcat configuration files according to your needs? This may be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271481/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-catalina-startup-bootstrap-when-running-tomcat).

Comment: This is not how Apache Tomcat should be started. There is `startup.bat` script.

Comment: do you have catalina.jar in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib?

Comment: catalina.jar is there in lib folder

Comment: this is not zip version of tomcat I have installed tomcat.exe  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin in this path I can find Tomcat7.exe by running this i can start but i want the status to be reflected in services(windows 7)

Comment: If you want [to run as service](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Tomcat7_service_application), then [run the service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Calling directly `java` is nonsense.